# `ColumnNotFound("id")` when inserting with SQLx

Tags: rust, mariadb, sqlx

I want to insert a new row and then get back the row I just inserted.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use sqlx::{FromRow, mysql::MySqlPoolOptions};
use tokio;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, FromRow)]
struct Session {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let pool = MySqlPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(10)
        .connect("mysql://me:password@localhost/time_tracker")
        .await
        .unwrap();
    let session: Session = sqlx::query_as("INSERT INTO sessions (name) VALUES (?) RETURNING *")
        .bind("Session name")
        .fetch_one(&pool)
        .await
        .unwrap();
    println!("{session:?}");
}
```

The table looks like this:

```
MariaDB [time_tracker]> DESCRIBE sessions;
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| start_time | datetime | YES |  | NULL |  |
| end_time | datetime | YES |  | NULL |  |
| pay_rate | decimal(10,2) | YES |  | NULL |  |

But I get this error. If I change it to `RETURNING name` I get the same error.

```
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:22:10:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ColumnNotFound("id")
```

If I change it to this:

```rust
    let row = sqlx::query("INSERT INTO sessions (name) VALUES (?)")
        .bind("Session name")
        .fetch_one(&pool)
        .await
        .unwrap();
```

I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:22:10:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: RowNotFound
```

The query works just fine if I do it in MariaDB directly.

```
MariaDB [time_tracker]> INSERT INTO sessions (name) VALUES ("Session name") RETURNING *;
```

| id | name | start_time | end_time | pay_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | Session name | NULL | NULL | NULL |

What am I doing wrong?